# VBA: Generating numbers for unique values of range and returning them to the range (simulating dice rolls)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to implement a random number generation in an Excel sheet. The process is such:

1. There are seven cells, each containing the number and type of dice to be rolled in standard notation (XdY+Z, where X is the number of Y-sided dice to roll, with Z being the bonus/penalty)
2. The numbers are tallied up into unique groups by roll types
3. The numbers are generated for each group (I have this step working, so this isn't the problem).
4. One extra roll is made for each group
5. The lowest number is dropped
6. The numbers are assigned to an output range, in order, so they match their dice rows.

I know I can extract the unique values from my input using a collection. I also already have a function which interprets the dice type and makes the roll. I am stumped though about being able to tally up the unique values, roll that many times + 1, drop lowest and then return them to the correct rows. Especially since I don't want to sort the results.

I would appreciate any help or any direction in which you could point me.

**Example:**

```
Input:   

1d6    
1d6    
1d8    
1d10    
1d4    
1d6   
1d4    

Divide into buckets: 3 x 1d6; 1 x 1d8; 1 x 1d10; 2 x 1d4    

Roll dice, with an extra roll for each bucket:    
4 x 1d6 - 4, 4, 5, 2    
2 x 1d8 - 8, 7    
2 x 1d10 - 1, 3    
3 x 1d4 - 1, 1, 4    

Drop lowest value, leaving the following numbers:    
1d6: 4, 4, 5    
1d8: 8    
1d10: 3    
1d4: 1, 4    

Assign them in order:    
1d6 - 4   
1d6 - 4    
1d8 - 8    
1d10 - 3    
1d4 - 1    
1d6 - 5    
1d4 - 4
```

This is the original function, which simply goes down the list, generates the roll (through a `RollDice` function that performs the roll), and places it in the correct output cell:

```
Sub GenerateOld()
    For i = 1 To 7
        Range("Dice_Output").Cells(i).Value = _
            RollDice(Range("Dice_Input").Cells(i).Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is my attempt at the new version of this code. Commented out are the sections I can't figure out:

```
Sub GenerateNew()
    Dim diceDictionary
    Set diceDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each Cell In Range("Char_Characteristics_Dice").Cells
        If diceDictionary.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            diceDictionary(Cell.Value) = diceDictionary(Cell.Value) + 1
        Else
            diceDictionary.Add Cell.Value, 1
        End If
    Next Cell

    For Each diceType In diceDictionary
        ' RollDice(diceType)
        ' Roll X drop lowest
    Next cont

    ' Place back into Dice_Output range in order
End Sub
```

Comment: I've written code that outputs a collection with the unique types of dice to roll using the cell's value as Key. I still need to figure out how to tally how many there are.

Comment: The people who help out here help you tweak existing code, not completely write it for you. Please make an attempt and post it in your question.

Comment: Use a dictionary, then increment the value of the dict when you encounter an existing key.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan! It works really well. I think I can figure out the rest, except for one thing - how can I drop (or set to 0) the lowest value in an array without sorting it beforehand? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still needed, but I used a set of arrays to tackle this problem. Here's a summary of how I approached it:

1. Get the values from the range in Excel, pass them to the first array
2. Set up the number of times the dice needed to be rolled
3. Pass the first array to a 2D array and populate it with info to finish
4. Use a temporary array to get values from the rolls and then paste back into the Excel sheet

   ```
   Sub roll()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim k As Long
   Dim lr As Long

   Dim upperbound As Long
   Dim lowerbound As Long
   Dim frequency As String
   Dim rolls As String

   Dim rng As Range
   Dim arr1D() As String
   Dim arr2D() As String
   Dim rollresult As Integer

   Dim arr_min As Variant
   Dim FirstCheck As Boolean
   Dim targetdi As Variant

   'Set the area with values for the dice roll simulation
   lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   'Clear the result area for roll results
   Range(Cells(2, "B"), Cells(lr, "B")).ClearContents

   Set rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(lr, "A"))

   'Collect unique values from the range
   For Each cell In rng
       If (cell <> "") And (InStr(frequency, cell) = 0) Then
           frequency = frequency & cell & "|"
       End If
   Next cell
   If Len(frequency) > 0 Then frequency = Left(frequency, Len(frequency) - 1)
   arr1D = Split(frequency, "|")

       'Set up the 2D array with a space for the number of rolls
       ReDim arr2D(LBound(arr1D) To UBound(arr1D), LBound(arr1D) To 3)

           'Copy contents from first (1D) array into the second (2D) array
       For i = LBound(arr1D) To UBound(arr1D)
           arr2D(i, 0) = arr1D(i)
           arr2D(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(lr, "A")), "=" & arr2D(i, 0)) + 1
           arr2D(i, 2) = Right(arr2D(i, 0), Len(arr2D(i, 0)) - InStr(1, arr2D(i, 0), "d"))

       'Keep rollin rollin rollin WHAT Keep rollin rollin rollin
           For j = 1 To (arr2D(i, 1))
               If ((arr2D(i, 2)) <> "") Then
                   rollresult = Int((Int((arr2D(i, 2) + 1)) - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                   rolls = rolls & rollresult & "|"
               End If
           Next j
       rolls = Left(rolls, Len(rolls) - 1)
       arr2D(i, 3) = rolls
       rolls = ""
       Next i

   For i = LBound(arr2D) To UBound(arr2D)
       temparray = Split(arr2D(i, 3), "|")
       arr_min = temparray(LBound(temparray))
           For j = LBound(temparray) To UBound(temparray) 'LBound(temparray) To UBound(temparray) - 1
               If temparray(j) < arr_min Then
                   arr_min = temparray(j)
               End If
           Next j

   'Remove the lowest value, but preserve the order
       For j = LBound(temparray) To UBound(temparray)
           If temparray(j) = arr_min And FirstCheck = False Then
               temparray(j) = ""
               FirstCheck = True
           End If
       Next j

   'Place the results back in the sheet
   For j = LBound(temparray) To UBound(temparray)
       If temparray(j) <> "" Then
           targetdi = arr2D(i, 0)
               For k = 2 To lr
                   If Cells(k, "A").Value = targetdi And Cells(k, "B").Value = "" Then
                       Cells(k, "B").Value = temparray(j)
                   End If
               Next k
           End If
       Next j

   Next i

   End Sub
   ```